# C# How to convert String into Time and Date format?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a short program which converts a string to both date and time format from a simple string.

However it seems that the String is not recorgnizable for the system to be converted into date time format due to the sequence of the string. The String that should be converted is an example like : "Thu Dec  9 05:12:42 2010"

The method of `Convert.ToDateTime` have been used but does not work.

May someone please advise on the codes? Thanks!

```
String re = "Thu Dec  9 05:12:42 2010";

DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(re);

Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: Please check out this webpage answered by another user which managed to get the answer fully right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436795/c-how-to-convert-irregular-date-and-time-string-into-datetime Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is often necessary to give it a hint about the specific pattern that you expect:

Edit: the double-space is a pain, as `d` doesn't handle that;

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(re.Replace("  "," "),
     "ddd MMM d hh:mm:ss yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: It outputs the error of unable to convert. The error of "System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)"

Comment: @JavaNoob - hmmm; that double space is a pain; I actually wonder whether you should simply cheat by passing in `re.Replace("  "," ")` (that is two spaces in the first quotes, one space in the second)

Comment: But what if the double spacing does not apply to 10+ dates? etc "Thu Dec 11 05:12:42 2010"? Thanks.

Comment: @JavaNoob - "d" handles two-digits fine; the distinction being that "dd" expects a leading zero.

Comment: The system does not recorgnise "Thu Dec 9 05:12:42 2010" even after the .replace method.

Comment: You answer is right however I tested the parameters against the other answer posted at the above comment and I think your missing a few parameters to the correct answer. But thanks for your help mate!

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx)

```
DateTime time; 
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(re,
     "ddd MMM d hh:mm:ss yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
      DateTimeStyles.None, out time)) {

    Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not in an acceptable format.", re);
}
```

Comment: If you aren't checking the result from `TryParseExact` you are probably assuming success - in which case, you should use `ParseExact` rather than `TryParseExact` - it will tell you your assumption is wrong.

Comment: @JavaNoob - You need to make sure that the input string matches the format you are expecting. There are solutions in the other answers/comments to fix some of the anomalies you have(eg @Marc's cheat comment: `re.Replace(" "," ")`)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fw7727c.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime("2010, 9, 12, 05, 12, 42"); 

Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the string input should have the double space but you could pull that out and use geoff's answer.

```
re = Regex.Replace(re, @"\s+", " ");
```

Other option is to adjust his match string accordingly.

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(re, "ddd MMM  d HH:mm:ss yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```